# How to get foreign key value from Stored Procedure while showing the list.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Following is the procedure that i have written in my application. But i want the LogSource Column in my list, but i am not able to get it from this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetApplicationLogs] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Skip int,
    @Pagesize int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 WITH TableDatawithRowNumber AS 
    ( SELECT dbo.ApplicationLog.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LoggedDate DESC) AS RowNumber,
        (SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Expr1
            FROM  ApplicationLog ) AS  TotalRecords        
   from ApplicationLog
 )    
    SELECT * FROM TableDatawithRowNumber
    WHERE RowNumber > @Skip AND RowNumber <= (@Pagesize+@Skip)
END
```

This table doensn't contain a LogSource column but it is having LogSourceID in it which is a foreign key in this table and the primary key in LogSource Table. I want to show that in my list but i am not able to get it in the view. I can only use LogSourceId but not LogSource. So please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to do a left join on the LogSource table

```
WITH TableDatawithRowNumber AS 
    ( SELECT dbo.ApplicationLog.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LoggedDate DESC) AS RowNumber, logSource.LogSource 
        (SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Expr1
            FROM  ApplicationLog ) AS  TotalRecords        
   from ApplicationLog as appLog
   left join LogSource as logSource on appLog.LogSourceId = logSource.LogSourceId
 )
```